# python dependency error while installing a package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, miniconda, intel-python

Whenever I install a python package I get this error. I am using **Intel** development python in **Miniconda** environment. The package is getting installed but always this dependency error arises.
   The following is an example.

```
pip install keras
```

The error is as is shown below.

```
(idp) D:\ml\tsk sir work>pip install keras
Requirement already satisfied: keras in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\ggmah\miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.12.0)
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2806, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 524, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2727, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3005, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1419, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\Users\ggmah\Miniconda3\envs\idp\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1607, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\ggmah\\miniconda3\\envs\\idp\\lib\\site-packages\\parso-0.5.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

I tried uninstalling and installing the whole intel distribution,still error is not resolved. There is no folder called *parso-0.5.1.dist-info* which gets created. I don't know how to resolve this internal error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the automatic package upload has broken Intel Anaconda. This has been escalated and is working to resolve. However, we are not sure if the same problem is causing your issue. Since this may not be a programming issue, you might try the [Intel Distribution of Python forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-for-python) as well for a deeper look into your issue.

Comment: I'm told this is fixed - you should retry.